# what i'am doing to retrive the date that date like this "dd/MMM/yyyy" only

Tags: winforms

i'am using datetimepicker inthat i'am applying  custom format like this"dd/MMM/yyyy" and date saving this format in  database. my query is retrive that date it come like"dd/MMM/yyyy 12:00:00 AM" .what i'am doing to retrive the date that date like this "dd/MMM/yyyy" only?

Comment: They are called DateTime for a reason

Comment: in the database i'am tacking only  date format

Comment: Please explain what is the datatype of the column where you plan to store the value extracted by the DateTimePicker control. Remember, dates shouls be stored in date/datetime columns

Comment: datatype of column i date,sql server execute that table the column value like this"dd/MMM/yyyy",but doubt is retrive that table ,the column value dispalys like this"25-Apr-2016 12:00:00AM",way that vaule coming in this format?

Comment: If the database column is a date then it is irrilevant the format that you see on video. Dates have no format, it is the code that display a date on video/printer that decides how to show the date using a conversion of the date value to string. In NET for example you have `DateTime.ToShortDateString` that take the date and transform it in a string with the current international settings of the PC where the code executes. So don't worry how the database shows the date values if they are stored in a date/datetime column.

Comment: okey,but how to tack only date value,can you explain it please.

Comment: The DateTimePicker stores the Date in the Value property. This property is a DateTime (NET doesn't have a _just Date_ type) so you always get the Date and the Time, of course the Time part is set to 12.00.00 AM. If you want you could use DateTimePicker1.Value.Today that is guaranteed to be the selected date with the Time part set to 12.00.00 AM but in your context it is the same value that you get from just the Value property

Comment: @nagarjuna I added answer please check it.

Comment: @nagarjuna did you get solution.

Comment: no could't get the solution  @JENKINS J

Comment: I coded with the same way i hot a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Using the below code.

```
  DateTime FinancialYearStart =Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0][6].ToString());
  string YearStart= FinancialYearStart.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```